# Facebook like button shows main domain like count on article pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I ran into a strange problem with the Facebook Like Buttons. After implementing it on the **articles pages** in SOME cases, but most of them, it shows up the like count for the **main page**.

**Article page example:**
http://www.men.hu/a-legnepszerubb-gyogyteak/eletmod/gasztro/225

This article should have 0 to 5 likes, not 200+. The main URL has 200+ likes. After parsing it with Facebook's **Linter** tool, it works just fine! Shows 0 likes and the Facebook like button starts working on the article page too. It seems like it clears some kind of cache, or re-parses the URL and corrects its data.

Debugging the parsed Facebook like button, the `data-href` tag seems to be correct, showing up the current page URL, not the main page.

Where can be the problem and how could I solve it? Any ideas are welcome as I feel like I tried already everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem with some pages, it turned out that the pages had been published, then someone disabled them and reactivated them again later.  While the pages were disabled, Facebook checked the page (they say they check pages every 24hrs to make sure the Page Title and other details are up to date) and got redirect to the home page, so used the 'like' count for that page.   However, Facebook cached the redirect so never picked up again that the page had been re-enabled.
We resolved the problem by manually re-linting the pages using the Facebook debugger, as you have done already.
Your page does seem to have the correct Like count just now (3), so looks like you may have resolved the problem for now.

Comment: Hi Stevie! I also thought about a similar issue with inactive/redirected pages being cached, and your comment gave me an idea. I think the problem is, that we review the inactive articles BEFORE publishing using a custom parameter in the URL. The like buttons are generated in the `data-href` with the real URL, without the special parameter. This way, Facebook is for sure redirected to the home page...

While we review the unpublished article, Facebook caches the redirected article page and this can be the reason of the false like count.

Thanks for your hint!